# extract contents from confusionMatrix saved in a list column in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

As shown in code below, after cross validation, I'm trying to extract model metrics for each fold. I saved all predictions in resampling, group the data by folds, compute the confusion matrix for each group, and saved the confusion matrix object as a list column `cm`. Now I need to extract metrics info, like precision, etc from the objects saved in the column. My example code is shown below.

```
library(caret)
iris2 = iris %>% 
    filter(Species != 'setosa') %>%
    mutate(Species = factor(Species))

train.control <- trainControl(method="cv", 
                           number=5,
                           summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                           classProbs = TRUE,
                           savePredictions='all')
rf = train(Species~., data=iris2,  method = 'rf',
           metric = 'ROC', trControl=train.control)
rf$pred %>% group_by(Resample) %>%
    do(cm = confusionMatrix(.$pred, .$obs),
       Accuracy = map(cm, ~.x$byClass['Precision']))
```

I got error message:

```
Error in .x$byClass : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I could not figure out why it does not work. My question is how I can modified the last line to make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ungroup()` and then simply `mutate` the `Accuracy` by accessing the specific part of the `list` for each fold you use `unlist()` to extract the element itself.

```
rf$pred %>% 
  group_by(Resample) %>%
  do(cm = confusionMatrix(.$pred, .$obs)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(neg_pred_value = map(cm, ~ .x[["byClass"]][["Neg Pred Value"]]) %>% unlist(),
         accuracy = map(cm, ~ .x[["byClass"]][["Precision"]]) %>% unlist())
```

Using the code above we get the following output as a `tibble`

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Resample                    cm neg_pred_value  accuracy
     <chr>                <list>          <dbl>     <dbl>
1    Fold1 <S3: confusionMatrix>      0.9090909 1.0000000
2    Fold2 <S3: confusionMatrix>      1.0000000 1.0000000
3    Fold3 <S3: confusionMatrix>      1.0000000 1.0000000
4    Fold4 <S3: confusionMatrix>      0.8181818 0.8888889
5    Fold5 <S3: confusionMatrix>      1.0000000 0.9090909
```